# Codeigniter MSSQL query error but fine in SQL Studio

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

Im using Codeigniter with MSSQL Database and having issues with queries, Im using the active record class in the following way

```
$this->db->protect_identifiers('content');
$this->db->protect_identifiers('url');
$this->db->select('url.url AS url, content.title AS title, content.id AS id');
$this->db->from('content');
$this->db->where('content.parent',$parent);
$this->db->where('content.menu',1);
$this->db->where('content.live',1);
$this->db->where('url."default"',1);
$this->db->join('url', 'content.id = url.content_id');
$this->db->order_by('content."order"','ASC');
```

Which is building the following query and causing an error

```
SELECT url.url AS url, content.title AS title, content.id AS id FROM content JOIN url ON    content.id = url.content_id WHERE content.parent = 0 AND content.menu = 1 AND content.live = 1 AND url."default" = 1 ORDER BY content."order" ASC
```

If i run the same query through SQL Studio it executes fine

Any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: `'url."default"'` to `'url.default'`

Comment: `'content."order"'` to `'content.order'`

Comment: yeah thats how i started which gives the error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.

Comment: can you tell what do you want to get from the tables exactly?

Comment: simply the title column from one and the url from the other linked by the ids, the error im now getting is on the order by clause

Comment: A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a field named "ORDER". Do not name fields in SQL Server that are reserved words.

Comment: I guess this is some of the issues when you transfer a MySQL to MSSQL